# Prevent duplicate record when inner join query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I used the inner join command to get the data from two tables.
But, when I run the SQL query.

I got the same record duplicated 48 times.

The SQL query I created is below

```
SELECT 
    ABS_LIMIT.B1_NAME, ABS_LIMIT.B2_NAME, ABS_LIMIT.B3_NAME, ABS_LIMIT.ELEM_NAME 
FROM 
    ABS_LIMIT
INNER JOIN 
    RTU_SCAN ON RTU+SCAN.B1_NAME = ABS_LIMIT.B1_NAME
WHERE 
    ABS_LIMIT.B3_NAME LIKE 'AMP%';
```

Does anyone have any idea how to remove the duplicate from the query result?

Comment: You can use DISTINCT keyword in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You never `SELECT` any columns from `RTU_SCAN` so you can use `EXISTS` rather than an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT a.B1_NAME, 
       a.B2_NAME,
       a.B3_NAME,
       a.ELEM_NAME 
FROM   ABS_LIMIT a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RTU_SCAN r WHERE r.B1_NAME = a.B1_NAME)
AND    a.B3_NAME LIKE 'AMP%';
```

Then, if there are duplicates in `RTU_SCAN` they will not propagate duplicate rows in the output.

---

Alternatively, you could use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.B1_NAME, 
       a.B2_NAME,
       a.B3_NAME,
       a.ELEM_NAME 
FROM   ABS_LIMIT a
       INNER JOIN RTU_SCAN r
       ON r.B1_NAME = a.B1_NAME
AND    a.B3_NAME LIKE 'AMP%';
```

However, it will probably be less efficient to generate duplicates and then filter them out using `DISTINCT` compared to using `EXISTS` and not generating the duplicates in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much. The duplicate issue is solved when I add DISTINCT to the query. the first suggestion doesn't work. When I run the query I got the error message SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: @user20061612 They both work in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bwcSXRop).